Getting the last and previous status of each ID in postgres
I have a postgresql table of tasks with various status of the task like this in table below. where in my last status of the task will be "Deleted"

I want to get the previous status of each task before it is converted as "Deleted" using Postgresql query.


We can use the LAG() window function here along with exists logic:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(Status) OVER (PARITION BY ID ORDER BY Updated) AS Old_Status
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT t1.ID, t1.Old_Status, t1.Status
FROM cte t1
WHERE t1.Status = 'Deleted' AND
      t1.Old_Status != 'Deleted' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM yourTable t2
        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND
              t2.Date > t1.Date
    );

The LAG() function finds, for each ID, the immediately preceding job status.  The exists clause ensures that any matching record returned is the latest one, which also has delete as the status.

Can you explain a little more about why the NOT EXISTS is necessary? Assuming there is no issue with multiple updates on the same day (I would have used a datetime, not a date), isn't that guaranteed by the partitioning?

The OP seems to want the latest record per ID which is also in a deleted status.

Here I want to have the old status only if it is different from last status (Deleted). In some cases I have status as "Deleted" for the previous date also. Once status is reached to "Deleted" that ID will keep on repeating. @TimBiegeleisen
